# Pipeline fails to change php version

Tags: php, ubuntu, azure-devops, yaml

I am having issues with a pipeline failing because it is not setting the correct version of PHP which then causes a composer install to fail but when manually running the same commands and checking php version the correct version is set.

The pipeline is setup as follows:

```
# PHP
# Test and package your PHP project.
# Add steps that run tests, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/php

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  phpVersion: 7.4

steps:
- script: |
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
    php -version
  displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'

- script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
  displayName: 'composer install'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

the failed job log shows as follows

```
Starting: Use PHP version 7.4
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/7743b650-1902-47f9-ae80-b9ee9186f3bb.sh
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/php7.4 for php not registered; not setting
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/phar7.4 for phar not registered; not setting
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/phpdbg7.4 for phpdbg not registered; not setting
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/php-cgi7.4 for php-cgi not registered; not setting
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4 for phar.phar not registered; not setting
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2023 22:56:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
Finishing: Use PHP version 7.4
```

previously this pipeline has worked and the log showed:

```
Starting: Use PHP version 7.4
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/2a36edba-2975-4d4b-906d-f1e2f0e869a7.sh
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.4 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar7.4 to provide /usr/bin/phar (phar) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phpdbg7.4 to provide /usr/bin/phpdbg (phpdbg) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php-cgi7.4 to provide /usr/bin/php-cgi (php-cgi) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4 to provide /usr/bin/phar.phar (phar.phar) in manual mode
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Nov  8 2022 11:33:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
Finishing: Use PHP version 7.4
```

I have manually run the following commands to update alternatives and set the php version on my ubuntu server:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4
php -version
```

which outputs the following:

```
user@server:~$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
user@server:~$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
user@server:~$ sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg7.4
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/phpdbg7.4 for phpdbg not registered; not setting
user@server:~$ sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi7.4
user@server:~$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4
user@server:~$ php -version
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Jun  8 2023 15:22:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

So it appears I can manually change the version of PHP but the pipeline is failing to do so. Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I have tried manually setting the php version

Comment: You have to switch to previous ubuntu version : `ubuntu-20.04`